# In Google BigQuery what is the benefit of ARRAY of STRUCT vs STRUCT of ARRAY?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm just getting to grips with ARRAYS and STRUCT in BigQuery

I'm wondering why one would choose this formatting

```
SELECT [STRUCT('Alice' AS col_1, 'Bob' AS col_2),STRUCT('Charlie' AS col_1, 'David' AS col_2)] AS names;
```

over formatting like this

```
SELECT STRUCT(['Alice','Charlie'] AS col_1, ['Bob','David'] AS col_2) AS names;
```

[output 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYRT9.png)

for both the output looks the same. What would be an example of why you would use one over the other? To me the first example makes more sense because I'd want Alice and Bob to be on the same record and it's more clear in the first example. However I've seen in Google's Vertex AI prediction output they use the second example. I.e. when outputting binary predictions they output as

```
SELECT STRUCT([0,1] AS class, [0.8,0.2] AS col_2) AS prediction;
```

instead of

```
SELECT [STRUCT(0 AS class, 0.8 AS prediction),STRUCT(1 AS class, 0.2 AS prediction)] AS names;
```

[output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUWFh.png)

When is the right time to use each?

Answer (score 0):

It should be based on what a row/entity represents.

In your first example, each element of the array could be a pair/team and you can add as many as you want.  Alice and Bob are pair 1, Charlie and David are pair 2...

The schema would be:

```
names (repeated field - struct)
 - col_1 (string)
 - col_2 (string)
```

In your second example, you have an entity with two types of names. An example here would be a list of names you like and names that you don't like. So Alice and Charlie would be liked (col_1) and you can add as many as you want to this list, on the other side Bob and David would be names that you don't like (and you can add as many here as well).

Schema.

```
names.col_1  (repeated field - string)
names.col_2  (repeated field - string)
```

In JSON format:

Example 1: `[{"col_1":"Alice", "col_2":"Bob"}, {"col_1":"Charlie", "col_2":"David"}]`

Example 2: `{"col_1":['Alice', 'Charlie'], "col_2":["Bob", "David"]}`

Comment: Thank you. I was confused regarding Google's formatting of the binary predictions. i.e 0 the negative class has its associated probability, 1 the positive class has its associated probability (1-negative class probability), so why haven't they paired it like the first example?

Comment: Also, slightly different question. I only started my career 6 years ago, BigQuery was my first introduction really to SQL, has STRUCT been widely used in SQL for a long time, or is it mainly a BigQuery thing? How common is it for it to be used?

Comment: Structs are not unique to BigQuery. In other databases and data warehouses, you may find similar concepts (column families), but not all will support it and in general, are likely used less often.

Repeated fields are less common and are usually not found in relational databases. For example, a common use case in BigQuery is flattening the table before exporting to a more traditional database. They're common in NoSQL databases (Firestore in GCP).